# How to calculate machine learning time for binary classification?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

I want to calculate the training and testing time for binary classification. How to calculate that if a given database D has A attributes and T records. Please any one help me?
or how to calculate the time complexity for binary classifier?

Comment: I do not understand your question.  Could you rephrase and clarify?

Answer (score 2):

By "time" do you mean the number of examples or the computation required to construct a classifier? If the former, the key quantity is the VC-dimension of the hypothesis class (i.e., collection of all classifiers you are willing to consider). The latter is strongly dependent on the representation (i.e., how you "view" the classifier in terms of algorithms and data structures) and in many cases can be NP-hard.